# How to send post request to a discord webhook via CMD

Tags: command-line, bash, cmd.exe, curl, discord

I have been trying to send post requests to a discord webhook for around an hour now but can't seem to figure out how to do it.
I want to send this:

```
    {
      "content": null,
      "embeds": [
        {
          "title": "Test!",
          "description": "nooo",
          "color": 16777215,
          "author": {
            "name": "Automated Tool Logging",
            "icon_url": "https://discohook.org/static/discord-avatar.png"
          }
        }
      ],
      "attachments": []
    }
```

And I have so far figured out that I have to use a curl request like this

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -X POST --data '{"content": null,"embeds": [{"title": "test","description": "temp\ntemp2","color": 16777215,"author": {"name": "Automated Tool Logging","icon_url": "https://discohook.org/static/discord-avatar.png"}}],"attachments": []}' -webhook link-
```

But when I tried it I got

```
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
curl: (3) bad range specification in URL position 2:
[{title:
 ^
```

And I couldn't find any examples of using embeds in curl requests. Any ideas on how to make it work?

Comment: I mean, the error message is clear, no? There is no URL. The command line looks incomplete. I ***strongly*** suggest not specifying POST data on the command line. Use a file instead.

Comment: Also, as for the tags: please decide. Is this about `cmd.exe` or Bash? Both are *very* different.

Comment: @DanielB The URL is right at the end, but I replaced it with "-webhook link-" in the example as anyone who has it can send messages through my webhook. Sadly, the only option I have is sending the post request from Microsoft batch & CMD (individually, but both are necessary).

Comment: So "bash" or "batch"?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Same thing

Comment: Please see the descriptions: [bash](https://superuser.com/tags/bash/info), [batch](https://superuser.com/tags/batch/info), [batch-file](https://superuser.com/tags/batch-file/info).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put `\` before every `"`, otherwise the `"` ends the string and causes a error. For example, the command that I used in the original post would look like this

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -X POST --data "{\"content\": null, \"embeds\": [{\"title\": \"test\", \"description\": \"temp temp2\",\"color\": 16777215,\"author\": {\"name\": \"Automated Tool Logging\",\"icon_url\": \"https://discohook.org/static/discord-avatar.png\"}}],\"attachments\": []}" [webhook link]
```